# Serilog log configuration to filter out 'System.Runtime' & 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting' logs in Azure Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

I wish to hide logs from 'System.Runtime' & 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting' in Azure application insights. This is the serilog logging configuration I have in yml file.

```
Serilog:
  MinimumLevel:
    Default: Information
    Override:
      Microsoft: 6
      System: 6
```

But I could still see the logs in application insights.
If in microsoft equivalent logging configuration, this will be the configuration below:

```
"Logging":{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "None",
      "System": "None",
  }
}
```

Did I get the equivalent Serilog logging configuration wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such log level as "None", try the following config

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System.Runtime": "Error"
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error"
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @roman-marusyk, If put Error, wouldn't all error and critical logs will output to appinsights?